# JDBC Realm error without message

Tags: authentication, jdbc, glassfish, jdbcrealm

I'm srtuggling at the moment with authentication of JDBC Realm. My situation is follows:

I have created JDBC Realm with GlassFish 3.1.2.2 and setup was done properly or at least I think so. I know how to config it and in fact it works fine but there's one big problem. The problem is this, when I have created a user with username and password and store it to database and try to login with its username and password it says Access Denied 403. Okay so I checked the problem which is "SEVERE: SEC1111: Cannot load group for JDBC realm user [username here]. Now I want to know what causes this problem but there's no error source given, I have checked GlassFish console, but no reason is given that causes the problem. I checked also for server logs to make sure whether the problem source is there but nothing.

So my question is how I can find out what causes this problem? To give more delightful information about this is this login system works when I add username to principal list. At the moment in my principal list there's only defined the user group name. So the role, principal name and group name are all the same. So of course I don't want to add all users who register as principals manually.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this. My problem was that I had incorrect Group table name. So as an advice if you get this kind of error in future make sure that your JDBC Realm configs and tables with their columns are correct.

[This page](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/GlassFishV3ErrorMessageReferenceSEC) helped to find the real cause of the error.